# Agregar datos en Base de Datos RDS con función Lambda

Tags: mysql, nodejs, aws, lambda, amazon-rds

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo creada una función Lambda que trae datos de una API (eso funciona), trae los datos pero cuando los intento guardar en la Base de Datos RDS (MySQL) no los almacena, según RDS en sus logs si registra la conexión a la base de datos, sin embargo, no guarda los datos y no me arroja ningún error.

**NOTA:** A nivel local si puedo agregar datos a la base de datos RDS y ejecutar la función, es desde Lambda donde no me permite hacerlo. Tengo habilitada para que se pueda conectar cualquier IP.

**NOTA 2:** Intente agregarle "await" a la función "mostrarDatos" y ahí si me da un error de que no puede leer "mostrarDatos".

```
require('./keys');
require('dotenv').config()
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { database } = require('./keys');
    
exports.handler = async function (event) {

    const conexion = mysql.createConnection({
        host: database.host,
        user: database.user,
        password: database.password,
        port: database.port,
        database: database.database
    });

    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(fetch('https://v1.nocodeapi.com/invrtir/google_sheets/rKPjqgwamsHcsOMU?tabId=source').then((res)=>{
            return res.json();
        }).then((json)=>{
            var recogerDatos = json;
            mostrarDatos(recogerDatos);
        })).on('error', (e) => {
            reject(Error(e))
          })
        })

        function mostrarDatos(recogerDatos) {

            for (let i = 0; i < recogerDatos.data.length; i++) {
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].PreOp == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].PreOp === undefined) {
                    recogerDatos.data[i].PreOp = 0;
                }
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].ProPost == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].ProPost === undefined){
                    recogerDatos.data[i].ProPost = 0;
                }
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].P1 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].P1 === undefined){
                    recogerDatos.data[i].P1 = 0;
                    p1Num = recogerDatos.data[i].P1;
                }else {
                    let p1 = recogerDatos.data[i].P1;
                    var p1Num = p1.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                    p1Num = Number(p1Num);
                }
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].P2 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].P2 === undefined){
                    recogerDatos.data[i].P2 = 0;
                    p2Num = recogerDatos.data[i].P2;
                }else {
                    let p2 = recogerDatos.data[i].P2;
                    var p2Num = p2.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                    p2Num = Number(p2Num);
                }
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].P3 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].P3 === undefined){
                    recogerDatos.data[i].P3 = 0;
                    p3Num = recogerDatos.data[i].P3;
                }else {
                    let p3 = recogerDatos.data[i].P3;
                    var p3Num = p3.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                    p3Num = Number(p3Num);
                }
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].P4 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].P4 === undefined){
                    recogerDatos.data[i].P4 = 0;
                    p4Num = recogerDatos.data[i].P4;
                }else {
                    let p4 = recogerDatos.data[i].P4;
                    var p4Num = p4.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                    p4Num = Number(p4Num);
                }
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].PM == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].PM === undefined){
                    recogerDatos.data[i].PM = 0;
                    pmNum = recogerDatos.data[i].PM;
                }else {
                    let pm = recogerDatos.data[i].PM;
                    var pmNum = pm.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                    pmNum = Number(pmNum);
                }
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].PM2 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].PM2 === undefined){
                    recogerDatos.data[i].PM2 = 0;
                    pm2Num = recogerDatos.data[i].PM2;
                }else {
                    let pm2 = recogerDatos.data[i].PM2;
                    var pm2Num = pm2.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                    pm2Num = Number(pm2Num);
                }
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].SL == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].SL === undefined){
                    recogerDatos.data[i].SL = 0;
                    slNum = recogerDatos.data[i].SL;
                }else {
                    let sl = recogerDatos.data[i].SL;
                    var slNum = sl.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                    slNum = Number(slNum);
                }
                if (recogerDatos.data[i].SL2 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].SL2 === undefined){
                    recogerDatos.data[i].SL2 = 0;
                    sl2Num = recogerDatos.data[i].SL2;
                }else {
                    let sl2 = recogerDatos.data[i].SL2;
                    var sl2Num = sl2.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                    sl2Num = Number(sl2Num);
                }
                var sql = `INSERT INTO datos (ticker, indice, fecha, preop, propost, p1, p2, p3, p4, pm, pm2, sl, sl2) VALUES ('${recogerDatos.data[i].Ticker}', '${recogerDatos.data[i].Index}', '${recogerDatos.data[i].Fecha}', ${recogerDatos.data[i].PreOp}, ${recogerDatos.data[i].ProPost}, ${p1Num}, ${p2Num}, ${p3Num}, ${p4Num}, ${pmNum}, ${pm2Num}, ${slNum}, ${sl2Num})`;
                conexion.query(sql, function (err, resultado) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(resultado);
                });
            }
        }

    return promise
}
```

Lo que me muestra CloudWatch:

```
2021-09-16T10:15:02.964-05:00   START RequestId: 25add6c2-f6da-4458-ac4d-f99dbf4085e4 Version: $LATEST

2021-09-16T10:15:13.086-05:00   END RequestId: 25add6c2-f6da-4458-ac4d-f99dbf4085e4

2021-09-16T10:15:13.086-05:00   REPORT RequestId: 25add6c2-f6da-4458-ac4d-f99dbf4085e4 Duration: 10120.09 ms Billed Duration: 10121 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 100 MB Init Duration: 242.40 ms
```

Imagen de que si toma la conexión:

[image: Conexion a RDS exitosa]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolví el inconveniente, la solución que encontré fue quitándole el "resolve" y "reject", junto con la función ".on()", ahora ya me guarda los datos sin problemas.

```
require('./keys');
require('dotenv').config()
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { database } = require('./keys');
    
exports.handler = async function (event) {

    const conexion = mysql.createConnection({
        host: database.host,
        user: database.user,
        password: database.password,
        port: database.port,
        database: database.database
    });

    const promise = new Promise(function() {
        fetch('https://v1.nocodeapi.com/invrtir/google_sheets/rKPjqgwamsHcsOMU?tabId=source').then((res)=>{
            return res.json();
        }).then((json)=>{
            var recogerDatos = json;
            mostrarDatos(recogerDatos);
        })
    })

    function mostrarDatos(recogerDatos) {

        for (let i = 0; i < recogerDatos.data.length; i++) {
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].PreOp == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].PreOp === undefined) {
                recogerDatos.data[i].PreOp = 0;
            }
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].ProPost == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].ProPost === undefined){
                recogerDatos.data[i].ProPost = 0;
            }
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].P1 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].P1 === undefined){
                recogerDatos.data[i].P1 = 0;
                p1Num = recogerDatos.data[i].P1;
            }else {
                let p1 = recogerDatos.data[i].P1;
                var p1Num = p1.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                p1Num = Number(p1Num);
            }
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].P2 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].P2 === undefined){
                recogerDatos.data[i].P2 = 0;
                p2Num = recogerDatos.data[i].P2;
            }else {
                let p2 = recogerDatos.data[i].P2;
                var p2Num = p2.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                p2Num = Number(p2Num);
            }
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].P3 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].P3 === undefined){
                recogerDatos.data[i].P3 = 0;
                p3Num = recogerDatos.data[i].P3;
            }else {
                let p3 = recogerDatos.data[i].P3;
                var p3Num = p3.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                p3Num = Number(p3Num);
            }
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].P4 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].P4 === undefined){
                recogerDatos.data[i].P4 = 0;
                p4Num = recogerDatos.data[i].P4;
            }else {
                let p4 = recogerDatos.data[i].P4;
                var p4Num = p4.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                p4Num = Number(p4Num);
            }
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].PM == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].PM === undefined){
                recogerDatos.data[i].PM = 0;
                pmNum = recogerDatos.data[i].PM;
            }else {
                let pm = recogerDatos.data[i].PM;
                var pmNum = pm.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                pmNum = Number(pmNum);
            }
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].PM2 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].PM2 === undefined){
                recogerDatos.data[i].PM2 = 0;
                pm2Num = recogerDatos.data[i].PM2;
            }else {
                let pm2 = recogerDatos.data[i].PM2;
                var pm2Num = pm2.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                pm2Num = Number(pm2Num);
            }
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].SL == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].SL === undefined){
                recogerDatos.data[i].SL = 0;
                slNum = recogerDatos.data[i].SL;
            }else {
                let sl = recogerDatos.data[i].SL;
                var slNum = sl.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                slNum = Number(slNum);
            }
            if (recogerDatos.data[i].SL2 == '' || recogerDatos.data[i].SL2 === undefined){
                recogerDatos.data[i].SL2 = 0;
                sl2Num = recogerDatos.data[i].SL2;
            }else {
                let sl2 = recogerDatos.data[i].SL2;
                var sl2Num = sl2.replace(/[$]/g, "");
                sl2Num = Number(sl2Num);
            }
            var sql = `INSERT INTO datos (ticker, indice, fecha, preop, propost, p1, p2, p3, p4, pm, pm2, sl, sl2) VALUES ('${recogerDatos.data[i].Ticker}', '${recogerDatos.data[i].Index}', '${recogerDatos.data[i].Fecha}', ${recogerDatos.data[i].PreOp}, ${recogerDatos.data[i].ProPost}, ${p1Num}, ${p2Num}, ${p3Num}, ${p4Num}, ${pmNum}, ${pm2Num}, ${slNum}, ${sl2Num})`;
            conexion.query(sql, function (err, resultado) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(resultado);
            });
        }
    }
    return promise
}
```